# Remember username in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have made a litle batch file, 
where you need to insert your account name of your computer.
I'm wondering if you could maybe write the account name to a text file,
so the program could remember it for next time you open it.
and don't have do enter it twice on the same computer.

Comment: Do you know that there is predefined by Windows the environment variable __USERNAME__ which contains the name of the user account running current command process? Run in a command prompt window `set` and you see all predefined environment variables (plus perhaps others defined by applications for entire machine or current user only) with their values.

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist username.txt (
  REM Read from text file:
  set /p "user="<username.txt
) else (
  REM Read from keyboard:
  set /p "user=Enter your username: "
  REM Write to text file:
  echo !user!>username.txt
)
```

Comment: thanks, but i got this now, and what does the REM read?

IF EXIST C:\un goto start
...
...
set /p name=Enter your name:
mkdir  c:\\un
echo %name% > c:\\un\username.txt
...
...
:start
set /p name=<c:\\un\username.txt

Comment: `REM` reads nothing. It's the command for `REMark`. All text behind `REM` is being ignored, it's just a comment meant to be read by humans only.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
@echo off
echo Prevous value is:
echo %mysetting%
echo.
set /p input="Enter new value: "
setx mysetting %input%
pause
```

Save this as .bat and run twice to see the persistence.

Comment: saving in a text file is a good idea, when the value should survive a reboot.

Comment: Why is saving the value in a text file a bad idea when it's not sensitive information?